# How do I force a data refresh in GatsbyJS when I'm using a Source plugin that calls a REST API without restarting Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby

Is it possible and how can I force GatsbyJS to reload external data? Either by disabling caching or limiting TTL in the cache?

I have a GatsbyJS running `gatsby develop` and it will reload code changes immediately, but it's hooked up to an external REST API via fetch using a source plugin. The data in GraphQL doesn't update once the data is loaded at build time / first load.

I'm using staticQuery(...) and non-static queries, both behave the same. I'd expect static to not update, but the normal query fires once and is forever cached.

From gatsby-site/gatsby-node.js

```
exports.createPages = async ({graphql, actions}) => {
    const pages = await graphql(`
         ...
    `);
```

Questions I've been unable to find useful answers to...

- Can I make it not cache at all?
- Can I limit how long it keeps the data?
- Is it in-memory, or if there's a folder on the disk could I delete it?

All help and ideas valuable. I couldn't find any other questions related, and even the tutorials on gatsbyjs.org indicate a server restart on data changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works but probably doesn't scale.

1. Start Gatsby with `ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT=true gatsby develop` or put the setting in the .env file
2. Use `curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/__refresh` to invoke a full refresh.
3. Alternatively, make it repeatedly call the hook to trigger a refresh periodically with `watch -n5 "curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/__refresh"` (every 5 seconds in this case, tune as needed) or put it in a crontab for unattended refresh with longer intervals.

Changes to source data will now be reflected, at the expense of hammering the source. I only needed this for development, and might not be a great idea for production use.

Comment: If I'm getting this right, a .env file is to be made with ```ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT=true``` And then in a terminal, I can run ```watch -n5 curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/__refresh```. Is that it?

Comment: Also, what are the options here for the production use?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'm not sure what the best approach is for production - that depends on your use-case. It may well be that the best thing *for you* is this, or maybe it involves actively rebuilding servers to cycle them hourly (or whatever interval) depending on how up-to-date you need the static version to be. Or maybe Gatsby has evolved now and has other options - I've not checked.

Comment: Also, don't expose the __refresh endpoint to the world, unless you want strangers to be able to hammer your backend servers. It's an easy vector for DDoS.

Comment: Thanks @antonyh! Probably obvious but I just want to point out that the URL might be something else than `http://localhost:8000` depending on your local setup. I'm running my gatsby develop on https and port 8080  with `gatsby develop --https -p 8080` so the POST request would be `curl -X POST https://localhost:8080/__refresh` for me.

Comment: @Calsal good point, and glad this helped you. I ran Gatsby on default ports & with HTTP, but this tip will probably help others (esp if there's redirects to https). As an aside, I'd use port 8443 as it's a commonly used HTTPS port instead of 8080 (which is not usually encrypted) but that's personal preference. I'm also surprised you didn't need `--insecure` or `-k` to ignore self-signed SSL - I'd expect cURL to reject the certificate and the request to fail.

Answer (score 4):

**Proposal of solution (Gatsby automated rebuild)**
The following example uses Strapi as a data source.

*PROS and CONS of the solution are in the end of post.*

1. Create webhook in Strapi (Settings>Webhooks>Add new webhook), which will be fired on create, edit or delete entry event. Set url with port eg. `http://newhost:1111/webhook` .
2. Dockerize your Strapi and Gatsby app. Gatsby's dockerfile does a trick as it is calling separated script which make build and serve.
3. Create node application working on `1111` port, which will be able to receive Strapi POST request on `localhost:1111/webhook` path. Then as a response node will run docker restart script, which in a couple of seconds refresh our Gatsby blog.

[image: strapi-gatsby-node]

**Cautions and code.**
There are few breakpoints which you have to do carefully in order to make your services work well.
First of all install locally your Strapi and Gatsby projects - [nice tutorial is here](https://strapi.io/blog/build-a-static-blog-with-gatsby-and-strapi). Don't forget to add all necessary plugins like graphql plugin in Strapi. Also make sure  that services are connected - Gatsby is able to fetch data from Strapi. If everything seems fine then let's save it into docker image.

Strapi Dockerfile

```
// Strapi Dockerfile
FROM strapi/base

WORKDIR /project

COPY ./package.json ./
COPY ./yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 1337

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Gatsby Dockerfile

```
//Gatsby Dockerfile
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine

WORKDIR /project

RUN npm install -g gatsby-cli

COPY . .
RUN yarn install

EXPOSE 3000

RUN chmod +x gatsby.sh
CMD sh gatsby.sh
```

gatsby.sh

```
//gatsby.sh
gatsby clean
gatsby build
gatsby serve -p 3000 --host 0.0.0.0
```

Here we have little magic. Every RUN command are called during docker image build but *CMD will be called only on image start*. So when we restart gatsby image, new build is created. Why we need fresh build? Each new Gatsby build fetch fresh data from Strapi.

Eg. command for creating docker Strapi image: `docker build --no-cache -t my-strapi:v1 .` . You call it inside Strapi project, also here must be a Dockerfile. After building two separated images, one for Gatsby and one for Strapi you can list them with `docker images`.

Time to run images
`docker run --add-host newhost:[machine ip] -p 1337:1337 strapi:v1`
`docker run --env API_URL="http://[machne ip]:1337" -p 3000:3000 gatsby:v1`

- `newhost` is an alias url used in Strapi's Webhook. Remainder: `http://newhost:1111/webhook` is a node app address.
- `API_URL` is an environmental variable used by Gatsby to connect with Strapi. (checkout your gatsby-config.js, I assume that your gatsby-source-strapi options have `apiURL: process.env.API_URL`).

Node.js app
On POST request call script which restart the docker Gatsby container.

```
// app.js
...
router.post('/webhook', function (req, res) {
  shell.exec('./docker-restarter.sh');
  res.send('POST request finished')
});
...
app.listen(1111);
```

docker-restarter.sh

```
//docker-restarter.sh
echo Calling docker ps to find container id
gatsby=$(docker ps -aqf "name=projects_gatsby_1")
echo Calling docker restart
docker restart $gatsby
```

`"name=projects_gatsby_1"` switch projects_gatsby_1 to the name of your Gatsby container

Start node with `node app.js`

[image: gatsby-strapi-refresh]
Now when everything is running, open two tabs: one with Gatsby site and second with Strapi. Add new post to Strapi. Checkout logs in Node.js console. When restart is done, make hard refresh on Gatsby's tab (for Chrome it is CTRL+SHIFT+R). Now you can see that new post is displaying in your Gatsby site.

**There are pros and cons to this solution:**

PROS:

- when blog post is added, deleted or edited in Strapi, Gatsby will refresh and show new data
- refresh process is fully automated

CONS:

- docker and node is in use
- each refresh demands restarting Gatsby container, because we are automatically creating new build (author of the question tried to avoid it)

Comment: This is good, but yes requires a restart/rebuild of Gatsby. The Strapi elements of the answer are useful for those using this (not me though). I'd also expect this to cause production problems unless multiple Gatsby servers are used and the restarts are staggered. Docker is irrelevent here - a Docker restart is fundamentally the same as any other restart. So this doesn't solve the problem of reloading without restarting, sadly.

Comment: As you pointed out, this solution seems to be more how to deal with Gatsby static nature, but not a real remedy.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this, I had the same problem. It wasn't productive to always trigger the endpoint manually with a script, so I decided to come up with a solution that is more simple. As we are working in browser, I wanted to have a keystroke to make Gatsby reload. Example code to build such a thing is, making a browser extension including code like this:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
    switch(command) {
        case 'refresh': 
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/__refresh', {
            method: 'POST',
        })
        break;
    }
});
```

package.json

```
"commands": {
    "refresh": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "windows": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
        "mac": "Shift+Command+Y",
        "linux": "Ctrl+Shift+Y"
      },
      "description": "Reloads Gatsby"
    }
  },
```

As a reference, here is a plugin that does exactly this:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gatsby-refresher/npdbjognnchpbocdpddhekiggpklcgpd?hl=de

Comment: Does it mean that every user can reload Gatsby with keystroke? Or it works only on local machine?

Comment: It works on your local machine only. The idea is, that you as a developer, don't need to restart Gatsby completely when the remote data model changes. The reload only triggers a new data model fetch